# VSTS multi configuration SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a multi-configuration vNext build I have configured in Visual Studio Team Services.  The build steps are configured in order as follows:

```
Nuget Restore
NPM Install
Grunt task
Fetch the Quality Profile from SonarQube
Build Solution
Build Functional Tests
Finish SonarQube analysis and upload results to SonarQube
Publish Artifacts
```

The build can be seen in VSTS running in parallel.  The problem is when the "Finish SonarQube..." steps run, they all contact the server at about the same time.  This (sometimes) makes the server timeout.  I have cranked up the SonarQubeAnalysisTimeoutInSeconds variable in the build to 1000 due to timeouts.  Is there any way to prevent the SonarQube from running on ALL three builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to enable/disable the specific build step during the build process for now. A similar user voice can be found here: [allow build vNext/preview tasks to be conditionally enabled or disabled.](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/8623600-allow-build-vnext-preview-tasks-to-be-conditionall)

If you don't want sonarqube run for some configuration, you need to create a separate build definition for them and disable/remove SonarQube step in the definition for now.